# How to print the error message of an exception of errorUserTitle

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am catching an exception on my system. The exception is thrown when I try to create a facebook ad with value less than 1.32.

I need to print the exception error message to the user. I can not print.

If I use dd ($ e) it prints this:

[image]

But I return $e or use json_decode ($e, true) it returns empty.

Does anyone know how I can print the error message of errorUserTitle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to run:

```
$e->getErrorUserTitle()
```

[Here](https://restfb.com/javadoc-2/com/restfb/exception/FacebookGraphException.html#getErrorUserTitle()) in the FB docs (i know it's java docs), you can see the `getErrorUserTitle()` helper. I believe it's same for PHP

Comment: Happy coding! :)